# webkit gradients and opacity

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

Attempting to make gradients that are cross browser:
`-webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(255,0,0,1) 100%)`
works great in chrome - top right is red and fades top opacity, and whatever color is in the first `rgba` doesn't affect the gradient (as it shouldn't).
If i try to mimic this in safari by:
`-webkit-gradient(linear, top right, left bottom, from (rgba(255,0,0,1)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0)))` it is not identical, as the `to(rgba(0,0,0,0))` affects the gradient (changing it's color affects the gradient).
Does anyone know how to mimic chromes transparency in safari? I've tried/googled a few techniques, nothing has worked thus far.

Comment: use http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: when I use what it produces in safari, the gradient is different

Comment: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#000000+0,ff0004+100&1+0,0+100;Custom - open this in chrome and then safari, they are different

Comment: looks like a bug in Chrome . I would say that in previous versions it worked ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue - safari is the only browser that takes the transparent RGBA color into account when attempting to blend halfway, this is easily solved by making the RBGA of the transparent end the same color as the opaque color - i.e. - `-webkit-gradient(linear, top right, left bottom, from (rgba(255,0,0,1)), to(rgba(255,0,0,0)))` will work